# Is center padding real

Tags: css

Is center padding real for css because as I use notepad++ it shows the tag in red coloring. I have tried putting a hyphen in between the words but nothing seems to be working can I get some answers for my problem please and thank you. This is the code that I'm trying to find out why the text is red in notepad++.

```
head{
width: 700px;
margin: 20px auto;
center padding: 20px;
}

body{
font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 25px 0 15px 0;
background-color: ;
center padding: 20px;
width: 700px;
margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Comment: Update your question to be more clear, and post some example code

Comment: No, `center padding` is not a valid CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

No, center padding is not real. If you are trying to center a div or item, you should use `margin: 0 auto;` or to center text in an item you can use `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Center padding is not a possible property in css, much like it would not be possible in real life.

If you are looking to apply the same padding all the way around an element (all four sides) you can simply use

```
padding:20px;
```

This will give you 20 pixels of padding top,right,bottom and left.

[See more examples here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your input on my question I really appreciate it Dom